# Polymorphim: How to create dynamic instance of Interface

Tags: c#, switch-statement, polymorphism

I'm going through this article to remove those switch case in c# and use polymorphism to achieve it.

https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Here is my code though:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Consolas
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var animalType = "Dog"; //consider this as an argument supplied to the app
            //How to create dynamic instance for IAnimal ???
            //Is Activator.CreateInstance the only way to achieve it ??
            //IAnimal animal = ..what here ?
            //animal.Bark();
        }
    }

    public interface IAnimal
    {
        void Bark();
    }

    public class Dog: IAnimal
    {
        public void Bark()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bow Bow");
        }
    }

    public class Cat: IAnimal
    {
        public void Bark()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Meow Meow");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I create instance for that Interface so that it can invoke that Bark method dynamically.

Can someone provide the best way of doing not just a work around.

Comment: Checkout [The Dependency Injection Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323705(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using the [Factory Pattern](https://www.dotnetperls.com/factory) to achieve that, an example would be something like this:

```
public class AnimalFactory
{
    public IAnimal CreateAnimal(string animalType)
    {
         //Here you can either have a switch statement checking for
         //type, or use Type.GetType(animalType) and then create an
         //instance using the Activator - but in the latter case you will
         //need to pass in the exact type name of course 

         //PS. You can also use an IoC container to resolve all
         //implementations of IAnimal and have a distinguishing property
         //that you use here to select the type you want, but I think
         //that's a bit off topic so won't detail it here
    }
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        var animalType = "Dog";
        var amimal = new AnimalFactory().CreateAnimal(animalType);
        animal.Bark(); 
 }
```

*EDIT*

One way to use an IoC container (AutoFac in this example) is to scan you assemblies and register all implementations of `IAnimal` keyed by the class name (if you were registering singleton instances, you could key by a property of the interface), something like the following:

```
class Program
{
    public static IContainer _container;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Register types
        Register();

        //Resolve a dog
        var dog = _container.ResolveKeyed<IAnimal>("Dog");
        //Resolve a cat
        var cat = _container.ResolveKeyed<IAnimal>("Cat");

        dog.Bark(); //Bow Bow
        cat.Bark(); //Meow Meow

        Console.Read();
   }

    static void Register()
    {
        //Get all types implementing IAnimal, you can of course scan multiple assemblies,
        //here I am only looking at the current assembly
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => !t.IsInterface && t.IsAssignableTo<IAnimal>());

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        foreach (var t in types)
        {
            //Use the type name as a key to the instance
            builder.RegisterType(t).Keyed<IAnimal>(t.Name)
              .InstancePerDependency(); //You want a new instance each time you resolve
        }          

        _container = builder.Build();            
    }
}
```

Of course you can still refactor that into a factory
PS. There might be a better way of registering all types within the assembly using AutoFac's [Assembly Scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html), but I couldn't see any way to combine that with a key per type.

Comment: +1 and just to note - there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a switch in this case. I would prefer it over the `Activator` approach.

Comment: @AntP true as long as the number of implementations is limited and the classes are known at compile time; the best option IMO would be resolving via an IoC container, but that seemed a bit overkill for the scope of the question

Comment: @AntP The animals can grow sometime later. So if I use the switch, wouldn't it be the same if I write it in the Main() method itself instead of CreateAnimal method

Comment: @KarthikChintala if you really need dynamic setup then yes you'll run into the same problem - the benefit being that if you have abstracted to a factory you can always rework to make the factory dynamic later...

Comment: @KarthikChintala if you want a scalable solution, then you can look at IoC container for C#, this will allow you to do something like `ioc.ResolveAllInstances<IAnimal>()` but then you'll need a property in `IAnimal` like a name of something that distinguishes the types, so you do `ioc.ResolveAllInstances<IAnimal>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Dog")`

Comment: @KMoussa can you shed some light on how to achieve with IoC. I'm trying with Autofac but not sure how to pass parameter and then call appropriate class based on param? Do I need to use `new` anyway to create class of particular type

Comment: @KMoussa Thank you. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case (just corresponding `string` to the `IAnimal` interface implementation) you can use *dictionary*:

```
  private static Dictionary<String, Func<IAnimal>> s_Factory = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<IAnimal>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {

    {"dog", () => new Dog()},
    {"hound", () => new Dog()}, // synonym to dog
    {"cat", () => new Cat()}    
  };
```

And so you put

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var animalType = "Dog";

      // if we sure that animal exists we can just call the dictionary 
      IAnimal animal = s_Factory[animalType]();

      animal.Bark();
  }
```

Or

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter animal type, please");
      String animalType = Console.ReadLine();

      Func<IAnimal> maker; 

      // If we not sure that animal exists, we have to check
      if (s_Factory.TryGetValue(animalType, out maker)) 
        maker().Bark();
      else
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I don't know such an animal"); 
  }
```

In *general* case, however, you have to implement *Factory Pattern* (see KMoussa's answer)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, usually I use `Activator.CreateInstance()` method, but as KMoussa said, using one factory to handle the creation of the concrete classes of `IAnimal` is a good (and recommended) way. This is my example of one of my project, which kinda similar.

```
public class ItemFactory
{
    /*
     * Singleton pattern for factory, cause generally a factory only has one instance through out the app.
     */
    private static ItemFactory itemFactory;
    public static ItemFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (itemFactory == null)
                itemFactory = new ItemFactory();
            return itemFactory;
        }
    }

    // method to create an instance of IItem, note the static modifier if you want to call it from base class, if
    // you use singleton, ignore static.
    public /*static*/ IItem CreateItem(string itemType)
    {
         Type type = Type.GetType(itemType);
         var temp = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
         return temp;
    }
}
```

later you can just,

```
var a = ItemFactory.Instance.CreateItem("RawItem");
a.RawItemMethod1();
a.RawItemMethod2();
```